# How to avoid QWidget from going out of sight

Tags: qwidget

Is there a way to avoid a QWidget from going out of sight?

I've got a line connecting some points; every point shows a widget (always the same) with some  values; if I move the mouse over a point close to the right margin of the monitor, the QWidget will be shown just partially (a part will be out of the monitor).

How can I force the widget to be fully shown when needed, maybe on the left of the mouse?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can compare the `QWidget`s `boundingRect()` and the `QDesktopWidget`s `boundingRect()` if outside, move the widget back ;)

Comment: Great! QDesktopWidget is the way!